# OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice Calc macro: is a cell's content currently overflowing?

Tags: openoffice-calc, automatic-properties, openoffice-basic, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-calc

I have a bunch of cells whose font size I'd like to tweak if their content is overflowing, until it all fits.  I'd like to write a macro to do this, unless there's a conditional formatting or other formulaic way of doing it.  Is there a property that tells whether a cell is overflowing?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score -2):

'open office 3

'get current document
oDoc = ThisComponent

' get first work sheet
oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)

'first cell in the work sheet

Cell   = oSheet.getCellByPosition(0, 0)
MsgBox Cell.CharHeight

Happy Coading :))

Comment: I don't think Cell.CharHeight tells me if the cell is horizontally overflowing from having too much content.  That's the property I can use to set the font size smaller once I find out whether it's overflowing, but it's the finding out first that I don't know how to do.